# nvidia driver problems with EDID

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia, xorg

I have EDID problems with proprietary NVIDIA drivers in Ubuntu 14.04. I have a Lenovo Y470 with dual NVIDIA/Intel graphics card. The resolution of the screen is 1366x768. I have tried drivers the official ubuntu repositories, the NVIDIA website and xorg_edgers ppa. Right now I am using  nvidia-331 from xorg_edgers.
In the Xorg.0.log file, I get the following warnings

```
     (WW)  NVIDIA(GPU-0) Unablet to read EDID for display device CRT-0
     (**) Using HorizSync/VertRefersh ranges from the EDID for display device (CRT-0)
```

several times  and then

```
     (II)modesetting(G0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 16716
     (II)modesetting(G0):Modeline 1366x768x0.0   72.33 1366  ....
     reporting 4 5 34 247
     have a mater to look out for
     adjust shatters 0 1366
     need to create shared pixmap
```

I will post the full xorg.0.log soon. I can only log in using recovery mode.

```
[    49.098] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[    49.098] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    49.098] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    49.098] Current Operating System: Linux sancar-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y470 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64
[    49.098] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=c9c05892-a3b6-43fc-b092-285426505e74 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    49.098] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:36:29PM
[    49.098] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    49.098] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    49.098]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    49.098] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    49.098] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jul  4 15:31:10 2014
[    49.136] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    49.136] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    49.697] (==) ServerLayout "layout"
[    49.697] (**) |-->Screen "nvidia" (0)
[    49.697] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    49.697] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia"
[    49.697] (==) No monitor specified for screen "nvidia".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[    49.697] (**) |-->Inactive Device "intel"
[    49.697] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    49.697] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    49.697] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    49.904] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    49.904]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.904] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    49.904]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.904] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    49.904]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.948] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    49.948]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.948] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    49.948]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.948] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[    49.948] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    49.948] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    49.948] (II) Loader magic: 0x7faa21a16d60
[    49.948] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    49.948]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    49.948]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[    49.948]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[    49.948]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    49.948] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    49.948] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    49.951] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0116:17aa:3981 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf1400000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00003000/64
[    49.951] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0df6:17aa:3981 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf0000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00002000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension Present
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    49.984] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    49.984] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    49.984] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    49.984] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    49.984] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    49.984] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    53.393] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    53.393]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    53.393]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    53.393] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  331.79  Sat May 17 23:58:32 PDT 2014
[    53.443] Loading extension GLX
[    53.443] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    53.443] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    53.758] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    53.758]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    53.758]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    53.794] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    53.844] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    53.916] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    53.916]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    53.916]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    53.916]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    53.916] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  331.79  Sat May 17 23:37:42 PDT 2014
[    53.916] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    53.940] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    53.940] (++) using VT number 7

[    53.956] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    53.956] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    53.956] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    54.021] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    54.021]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    54.021]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    54.021] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[    54.021] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    54.021] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    54.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    54.107] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    54.107]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    54.107]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    54.107] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    54.107] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    54.107] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    54.187] (II) modesetting(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    54.187] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "nvidia" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    54.187] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    54.187] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    54.187] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    54.187] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    54.187] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
[    54.187] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
[    54.188] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    55.621] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    55.621] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20130102)
[    55.622] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 550M (GF108) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    55.622] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
[    55.622] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.08.4b.00.02
[    55.623] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    55.625] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GT 550M at PCI:1:0:0
[    55.625] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0 (boot, connected)
[    55.625] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    55.625] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    55.625] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    55.625] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    55.628] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    55.628] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    55.628] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    55.628] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    55.628] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    55.628] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    55.628] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1024 x 768
[    55.631] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-0's EDID; cannot compute DPI
[    55.631] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-0's EDID.
[    55.631] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    55.631] (==) modesetting(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    55.631] (==) modesetting(G0): RGB weight 888
[    55.631] (==) modesetting(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    55.631] (II) modesetting(G0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[    55.631] (II) modesetting(G0): Output LVDS-1-0 has no monitor section
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Output VGA-1-0 has no monitor section
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Output HDMI-1-0 has no monitor section
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-0 has no monitor section
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output LVDS-1-0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 414c  Serial#: 0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Year: 2010  Week: 0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Digital Display Input
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 31  vert.: 17
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Gamma: 2.20
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): redX: 0.580 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.310 greenY: 0.550
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): blueX: 0.155 blueY: 0.155   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 72.3 MHz   Image Size:  309 x 174 mm
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1414  h_sync_end 1446 h_blank_end 1526 h_border: 0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 770  v_sync_end 775 v_blanking: 790 v_border: 0
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0):  SAMSUNG
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0):  140AT20-L01
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID (in hex):
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0):  00ffffffffffff004ca34c4100000000
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0):  00140103801f1178ea87f594574f8c27
[    55.633] (II) modesetting(G0):  27505400000001010101010101010101
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0):  010101010101411c56a0500016303020
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0):  250035ae100000190000000f00000000
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0):  000000000025d9066a00000000fe0053
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0):  414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0):  00313430415432302d4c30310a2000e1
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1-0
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1366x768"x60.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1408 1440 1520  768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x120.1  133.47  1024 1100 1212 1400  768 768 770 794 doublescan -hsync +vsync (95.3 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "960x720"x120.0  117.00  960 1024 1128 1300  720 720 722 750 doublescan -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "928x696"x120.1  109.15  928 976 1088 1264  696 696 698 719 doublescan -hsync +vsync (86.4 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "896x672"x120.0  102.40  896 960 1060 1224  672 672 674 697 doublescan -hsync +vsync (83.7 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "960x600"x120.0   77.00  960 984 1000 1040  600 601 604 617 doublescan +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "960x540"x120.0   69.25  960 984 1000 1040  540 541 544 555 doublescan +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x120.0   81.00  800 832 928 1080  600 600 602 625 doublescan +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "840x525"x120.0   73.12  840 892 980 1120  525 526 529 544 doublescan -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "840x525"x119.8   59.50  840 864 880 920  525 526 529 540 doublescan +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x512"x120.3   51.56  800 800 828 832  512 512 514 515 doublescan +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "700x525"x120.0   61.00  700 744 820 940  525 526 532 541 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x512"x120.0   54.00  640 664 720 844  512 512 514 533 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x450"x119.8   53.25  720 760 836 952  450 451 454 467 doublescan -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x120.0   54.00  640 688 744 900  480 480 482 500 doublescan +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "680x384"x119.6   42.38  680 716 784 888  384 385 390 399 doublescan -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "680x384"x119.9   36.00  680 704 720 760  384 385 390 395 doublescan +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "576x432"x120.1   40.81  576 608 668 760  432 432 434 447 doublescan -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "512x384"x120.0   32.50  512 524 592 672  384 385 388 403 doublescan -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "400x300"x120.6   20.00  400 420 484 528  300 300 302 314 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "400x300"x112.7   18.00  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[    55.634] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "320x240"x120.1   12.59  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[    55.635] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output VGA-1-0
[    55.635] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-0
[    55.636] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-0
[    55.636] (II) modesetting(G0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    55.636] (==) modesetting(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    55.636] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    55.636] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    55.636] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    55.636] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    55.636]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    55.636]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    55.636] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    55.636] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    55.636] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    55.722] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    55.722]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.1.0
[    55.722]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    55.722] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    55.751] (==) modesetting(G0): Backing store enabled
[    55.751] (==) modesetting(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[    55.751] (II) modesetting(G0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    55.751] (==) modesetting(G0): DPMS enabled
[    55.751] (WW) modesetting(G0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" is not used
[    56.060] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    56.060] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    56.186] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    56.255] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    56.376] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    56.376] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    56.376] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    56.376] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    56.376] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    56.377] Loading extension XINERAMA
[    56.377] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    56.377] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    56.377] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    56.377] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    56.377] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    56.377] (--) RandR disabled
[    56.415] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    56.492] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    56.492] (II) modesetting(G0): Damage tracking initialized
[    57.742] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    57.765] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
```

removed evdev- related stuff

```
[    58.244] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.244] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.244] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.244] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.261] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.261] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.261] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.261] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.277] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.277] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.277] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.277] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.327] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.327] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.327] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.327] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.344] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.344] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.345] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.345] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.361] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.361] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.361] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.361] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.378] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.378] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.378] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.378] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.381] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 16716
[    58.381] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    58.381] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    58.382] reporting 4 5 41 296
[    58.413] have a master to look out for
[    58.413] adjust shatters 0 1366
[    58.414] need to create shared pixmap 1(WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.578] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.578] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.578] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.595] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.595] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.595] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.595] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.596] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 16716
[    58.596] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    58.596] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    58.598] reporting 4 5 34 247
[    58.612] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.612] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.612] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.612] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.629] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.629] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.629] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.629] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.629] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 16716
[    58.629] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    58.629] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    58.631] reporting 4 5 34 247
[    58.632] have a master to look out for
[    58.765] need to create shared pixmap 1(WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.778] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.778] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.778] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.796] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    58.796] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    58.796] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    58.796] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    58.796] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 16716
[    58.796] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    58.796] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz eP)
[    58.798] reporting 4 5 34 247
[    58.830] have a master to look out for
[    58.831] adjust shatters 0 1366
[    58.832] need to create shared pixmap 1(II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
```

removed unrelated parts

```
[    60.338] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[    60.754] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Install the `xserver-xorg-video-all` driver package.

Comment: @user296776 it was already installed. Why would that work anyway?